# Re-size a bitmap using "Nearest Neighbor" in .net

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, resize, nearest-neighbor

I have some low detail images I'm rendering to the screen.  I'm using a bitmap as a buffer.  Is there a way to re-size the bitmap (using "Nearest Neighbor") in .net?

I'm using VB.net so all .net solutions are acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple Winforms example that draws a scaled image added as a resource with the name "SmallImage" with nearest neighbor interpolation:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
        Me.bmp = My.Resources.SmallImage
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half
        Dim h = Me.ClientSize.Width * bmp.Height / bmp.Width
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.ClientSize.Width, h))
    End Sub

    Private bmp As Bitmap

End Class
```